# AdonisJS - Update many items from array

Tags: postgresql, adonis.js

So I am using AdonisJS and PostgreSQL for my backend and I am trying to find a way to update many from an array without doing a loop, either by SQL or using AdonisJS model methods.

I have an array like this one (no. of items is indefinite):

```
[
      {
        "id":5,
        "name":"aaaaaaa",
        "price":"5689.78",
      },

      {
        "id":6,
        "name":"bbbbb",
        "price":"5689.78",
      },

      {
        "id":7,
        "name":"cccc",
        "price":"5689.78",
      }
]
```

lets say I have table called products

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to finally work, I used an INSERT query with an ON CONFLICT clause

```
    await Database.raw(
      "INSERT INTO products (id, name, price) " +
      "VALUES (5, 'aaaaaaa', 5689.78), (6, 'bbbbb', 5689.78), (7, 'cccc', 5689.78) " +
      "ON CONFLICT (id) " +
      "DO UPDATE SET " +
      "name = EXCLUDED.name, " +
      "category_id = EXCLUDED.category_id, " +
      "price = EXCLUDED.price, " +
      "units = EXCLUDED.units, " +
      "priority = EXCLUDED.priority, " +
      "is_hidden = EXCLUDED.is_hidden"
    )
```

To update it dynamically, I will give this sample code

```
     const requestPayload = [
      {
        "id":5,
        "name":"aaaaaaa",
        "price":"5689.78",
      },

      {
        "id":6,
        "name":"bbbbb",
        "price":"5689.78",
      },

      {
        "id":7,
        "name":"cccc",
        "price":"5689.78",
      }
    ]

    // create a string that translate the request payload
    // to this format = "(5, 'aaaaaaa', 5689.78), (6, 'bbbbb', 5689.78), (7, 'cccc', 5689.78)"
    const values = requestPayload.reduce((result, item) => {
      const itemKeys = ['id', 'name', 'price']

      // create a string that translate the product item obj
      // to this format (4, 'aaaa', 111)
      const productValues = itemKeys.reduce((res, productKey) => {
        const productValue = item[productKey]

        if (productKey === 'name') {
          res.push(`'${productValue}'`)
          return res
        }

        res.push(`${productValue}`)

        return res
      }, []).join(', ')

      result.push(`( ${productValues} )`)
      return result
    }, []).join(', ')

    await Database.raw(
      "INSERT INTO products (id, name, price) " +
      "VALUES " + values +
      "ON CONFLICT (id) " +
      "DO UPDATE SET " +
      "name = EXCLUDED.name, " +
      "category_id = EXCLUDED.category_id, " +
      "price = EXCLUDED.price, " +
      "units = EXCLUDED.units, " +
      "priority = EXCLUDED.priority, " +
      "is_hidden = EXCLUDED.is_hidden"
    )
```

I feel like there should be a better answer using an UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT statement, so if you have a better answer please answer this question!

UPDATE:

I have now created a query using an UPDATE statement

```
    await Database.raw(
      "UPDATE products " +
      "SET " +
      "name = prod.name, " +
      "price = prod.price, " +
      "FROM " +
      "( VALUES (5, 'aaaaaaa', 5689.78), (6, 'bbbbb', 5689.78), (7, 'cccc', 5689.78) ) as prod (id, name, price) " +
      "WHERE products.id = prod.id"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lucid perspective.

```js
const Product = use('App/Models/Product')

const productData = request.collect(['id', 'name', 'price'])
await Product.createMany(productData)
```

> The `createMany` method makes `n` number of queries instead of doing a bulk insert, where `n` is the number of rows.

or you can do bulk insert using this code. You have to define the returning column explicitly.

```js
await Database
  .insert(array)
  .into('products')
  .returning('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can map through the values of array and then update

```
const values = [
      {
        "id":5,
        "name":"aaaaaaa",
        "price":"5689.78",
      },

      {
        "id":6,
        "name":"bbbbb",
        "price":"5689.78",
      },

      {
        "id":7,
        "name":"cccc",
        "price":"5689.78",
      }
]

  values.map(async value =>{
      await Row.merge(value).save()
  })
```